# Why do we need to create the DNS A record for API Gateway custom domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

According to the [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-api-gateway.html), after we create a custom domain name for our API Gateway, we need to create a Route 53 DNS A record, which basically routes the traffic to the custom domain name to the target domain. I'm curious why AWS doesn't do it automatically and what happens under the hood when we create the custom domain name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This section explains it well:

> An alias record is a Route 53 extension to DNS. It's similar to a CNAME record, but you can create an alias record both for the root domain, such as example.com, and for subdomains, such as www.example.com. (You can create CNAME records only for subdomains.

First, the DNS record is a special resource record only supported by AWS route 53, and it supports both the root domain, and subdomains. Normal DNS uses CNAME records, which don't work at the root domain.

Secondly, as to why it's not automatically created for you, well I'm not sure. But its easy to do manually. Select the alias record type, and it will bring up the list of available resources to alias.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand the difference between the CNAME record and the Alias record.

If you look at the custom domain, there is the custome domain name and also the target domain. The way I see it is that with the custom domian itself, we should be able to route the traffic to the target. This should be done under the hood instead of the user creating a new Alias record by themselves. It's a bit confusing. That's why I want to know what happens when you create the custom domain.

Comment: yes, the custom domain can route traffic to your endpoint, but you need DNS to do that of course. There must be a record in Route 53, which is the DNS service that AWS uses for this function.  Under the hood, you have to have DNS so any client can access the endpoint from the internet.

Comment: @BenjaminHao *"what happens when you create the custom domain"* is that API Gateway creates an internal configuration record so that after you set up DNS, when a request arrives for that hostname (as set by the client in the TLS SNI field and the HTTP `Host` header) API Gateway knows which API/stage should handle the request.  While they could create the DNS entry for you, that is not as simple as you may assume.  The appropriate Route 53 hosted zone could be in an entirely different AWS account, or your account could have multiple hosted zones for the same domain, in complex cases.